# Only expose routes with prefix /wp-json on WordPress using Apache

Tags: htaccess, apache, headless

Pretty straightforward:

I want to only expose routes with the /wp-json prefix so that I can use headless WordPress without exposing the rest of my WordPress site to the internet.

I'm running this on Apache, but haven't yet figured out the proper syntax for .htaccess.

So far I have tried:

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /wp-json*>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory /wp-json*/*>
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

and

```
<Directory "/wp-json/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

My .htaccess is located inside of the `public_html` root directory. I'm not sure if I've got the .htaccess in the wrong directory or, if the syntax I'm using just isn't working. Any tips?

**EDIT:**
MrWhite's example worked. I ultimately [added another rewrite rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155991/using-multiple-rewrite-rules#answer-12156027) for /wp-admin and my final `.htaccess` is as follows (note the `[F]` changes to a `[C]` on the wp-json RewriteRule):

```
RewriteEngine on

# Reject any user requests that are not prefixed "/wp-json"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !wp-json($|/) - [C]
RewriteRule !wp-admin($|/) - [F]

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following mod_rewrite directives instead at the *top* of your root `.htaccess` file (before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section):

```
# Reject any user requests that are not prefixed "/wp-json"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule !wp-json($|/) - [F]
```

Requested URLs that are not prefixed `/wp-json` (or `/wp-json/`) are rejected with a 403 Forbidden.

The `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to ensure that only requests from the client are blocked and not internally rewritten requests to `index.php` (the WordPress front-controller). `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty on the initial request and set to "200" (as in 200 OK status) after the first successful rewrite.

> ```
> <Directory />
>     AllowOverride None
> </Directory>
> <Directory /wp-json*>
>     AllowOverride All
> </Directory>
> <Directory /wp-json*/*>
>     AllowOverride None
> </Directory>
> ```

`<Directory>` and `AllowOverride` are server-only directives and will trigger a 500 Internal Server Error if used in `.htaccess`. However, `AllowOverride` enables/disables `.htaccess` overrides (it doesn't *block* access) - which is not what you want to do here (`.htaccess` overrides are probably already enabled). And `/wp-json` is not a physical "directory" on the filesystem, so the `<Directory>` directive does not apply here.

> ```
> Order deny,allow
> Deny from all
> Allow from all
> ```

Having `Deny from all` and `Allow from all` in the same context doesn't really make sense. (You would need to disable access for the root and enable access for the *specific* URL-path prefix.) However, `Order`, `Deny` and `Allow` are Apache 2.2 directives and you are more likely to be on an Apache 2.4 server. These directives are now deprecated in favour of the Apache 2.4 `Require` group of directives.